# LambdaExpression CompileToMethod

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, reflection.emit

I Have a few lines of code

```
public void CreateMethod<TContract>(Expression<Action<TContract>> method)
{
   var innerMethod = Builder.DefineMethod("SomeName",MethodAttributes.Private);
   method.CompileToMethod(innerMethod);
   //more code
}
```

However the second line fails. I've tried with different versions of DefineMethod with little luck.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, `CompileToMethod` requires a static method as its argument (see [here](http://dlr.codeplex.com/workitem/1378?ProjectName=dlr)).  Therefore, you need to add `MethodAttributes.Static` to `innerMethod`'s definition.

Comment: As further comments it's worth noting that you cannot pass an argument of the type the the method is compiled into

Comment: Here is a work-around based on interfaces:
http://justinmchase.com/2009/01/08/lambdaexpressioncompiletomethod-e280a6-not-nearly-as-cool-as-i-had-hoped/