# When compiling a LambdaExpression with nested LambdaExpressions, will they compile also?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

When building a LambdaExpression at runtime, if I use a LambdaExpression as a parameter to a call expression (like when using Linq), then compile the main lambda, does the nested lambda also compile or does it need to?

The code functions the same if I use the LambdaExpression as a parameter to a method taking `Func<T, T2>` or if I compile it and use a `Expression.Constant` over the compiled `Func`.

Not compiled:

```
    var selectParam = Expression.Parameter(propType, "selectParam");
    var selectExp = Expression.Call(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().First(a => a.Name == "Select" && /*Func<TSource,TResult>*/ a.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(propType, typeof(int)),
                                    whereExp,
                                    Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(selectParam, "Length"), selectParam));
```

Compiled:

```
    var selectParam = Expression.Parameter(propType, "selectParam");
    var selectExp = Expression.Call(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().First(a => a.Name == "Select" && /*Func<TSource,TResult>*/ a.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(propType, typeof(int)),
                                    whereExp,
                                    Expression.Constant(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(selectParam, "Length"), selectParam).Compile())); //compile
```

The expressions I'm building are called millions of times in a loop so I'd like to know if compiling the outer lambda compiles the inner lambdas properly.

Since this isn't easy to explain, see my fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gGiGRG).

I'm pretty sure they *won't* be compiled as the methods being called could want them as Expressions to parse them. In this case, is there a runtime performance gain to compile them when used like this?

Thinking at a higher level, When used in a standard way in a loop - is this optimized at all? Certainly they aren't compiled on every call when doing linq over an array or such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes, each inner lambda will be compiled.

---

I slightly modified your first method (but it generates same expression):

```
private static Expression<Func<int>> ActuallyInnerAlsoCompile()
{
    var strType = typeof(string);
    var intType = typeof(int);
    var enumearbleType = typeof(Enumerable);

    var array = Expression.NewArrayInit(strType, Expression.Constant("test"), Expression.Constant("test2"));

    var x = Expression.Parameter(strType, "whereParam");
    var whereExp = Expression.Call(enumearbleType,
        "Where",
        new[] {strType},
        array,
        Expression.Lambda(Expression.NotEqual(Expression.PropertyOrField(x, "Length"), Expression.Constant(4)), x));

    var selectExp = Expression.Call(enumearbleType,
        "Select",
        new[] {strType, intType},
        whereExp,
        Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(x, "Length"), x));

    var firstOrDefault = Expression.Call(enumearbleType,
        "FirstOrDefault",
        new[] {intType},
        selectExp);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(firstOrDefault);
}
```

Now you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764705/4685428) and compile your expression into new assembly:

```
var lambda = ActuallyInnerAlsoCompile();

var dynamicAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    new AssemblyName("dynamicAssembly"),
    AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

var dm = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("dynamicModule", "dynamic.dll");
var dt = dm.DefineType("dynamicType");
var m1 = dt.DefineMethod(
    "dynamicMethod",
    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

lambda.CompileToMethod(m1);
dt.CreateType();

dynamicAssembly.Save("dynamic.dll");
```

If you open that dynamic.dll with some IL tool (dotPeek for example) you will see something like:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: dynamicType
// Assembly: dynamicAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 94346EDD-3BCD-4EB8-BA4E-C25343918535

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class dynamicType
{
  public static int dynamicMethod()
  {
    return ((IEnumerable<string>) new string[2]
    {
      "test",
      "test2"
    }).Where<string>(new Func<string, bool>(dynamicType.\u003CExpressionCompilerImplementationDetails\u003E\u007B1\u007Dlambda_method)).Select<string, int>(new Func<string, int>(dynamicType.\u003CExpressionCompilerImplementationDetails\u003E\u007B2\u007Dlambda_method)).FirstOrDefault<int>();
  }

  private static bool \u003CExpressionCompilerImplementationDetails\u003E\u007B1\u007Dlambda_method(string whereParam)
  {
    return whereParam.Length != 4;
  }

  private static int \u003CExpressionCompilerImplementationDetails\u003E\u007B2\u007Dlambda_method(string whereParam)
  {
    return whereParam.Length;
  }
}
```

Or (without ugly unicode escape sequences)
 [image]

Comment: If this is the case and inner lambdas are always compiled, how would you pass the lambda in as an Expression instead of a Func?  For a QueryProvider to parse?

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi I'm not sure I've understand your comment. Do you want to generate an expression and pass it to the QueryProvider? If so you do not need a `Compile` call at all. Could you please edit (or create a new one) question and explain (with examples)  what you trying to achive?

Comment: I simply meant if the call were to Queryable.Where instead of Enumerable.Where.  And "Compile" was not called on the inner lambdas (like above).  I would think at that point the method takes an Expression so they are not converted to Func automatically.